# how to skip/ignore malformed CSV when using CSV.foreach?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I tried to read large csv file

but the csv are on bad condition

so some of it's line throwing `CSV::MalformedCSVError`

I just want to ignore the error line and move onto next line

I tried to add begin rescue but seems my code is not working, it stopped at the error

my current code

```
require 'csv'    

begin
  CSV.foreach(filename, :headers => true) do |row|
    Moulding.create!(row.to_hash)
  end
rescue
  next
end
```

Comment: Your question cannot be answered without knowing what the file looked like. I suggest you attempt to reproduce the error with a file containing just a few lines, then post those lines,  together with the error message obtained and the identity of the line on which the exception was raised.

Comment: if you need to see the file, then what I'm trying to do is not possible right?, then the correct approach is to modify/fix the csv files ?

my error is like this `CSV::MalformedCSVError (Unquoted fields do not allow new line <"\r"> in line 10250.)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with the `foreach` method because the exception does not seem to be raised within the block but rather within the `foreach` method itself, but something like this should work.  In this case the exception is raised on the call to shift, which you can then rescue out of.

```
require 'csv'    

csv_file = CSV.open("test.csv", :headers => true)
loop do
    begin
      row = csv_file.shift
      break unless row 
      p row
    rescue CSV::MalformedCSVError
      puts "skipping bad row"
    end
end
```

BTW your code above does not run because when you moved `begin` `rescue` to surround the `foreach` method  , `next` is no longer valid in that context.  Commenting out the `next` statement the code runs but when the exception is raised in the `foreach` method the method just ends and program moves on to the rescue block and does not read any more lines from the file.

Comment: does this line `csv_file = CSV.open("test.csv", :headers => true)` means I load the whole file into memory though?

Comment: Not according to the doc.  shift will read one line from the file.  https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-shift